# Horizontal to Vertical Format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with these values:

```
X1  X2      X3
s1  45.11   1
s1  45.13   1
s1  53.42   2
s1  51.41   2
s2  96.76   3
s2  96.65   3
s4  77.9    4
s1  80.46   5
s3  43.58   2
s1  43.12   2
s1  41.51   3
s4  41.97   3
s1  108.97  6
s3  117.46  6
s4  40      3
s4  40      3
s5  25.4    1
s5  25.5    1
```

I want to convert it to a data frame in this kind of format:

```
    s1     s2   s3  s4  s5
1   45.12   0   0   0   25.45
2   49.32   0   43.58   0   0
```

In this, the values are the mean values of the `X2` column above that match the criteria, i.e., are part of row `s1` and have the value of `X3` as 1.

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Possible dupe [aggregate and reshape from long to wide](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23611735/903061), though there's probably a better one out there.

Comment: I don't understand what is your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `value.var` argument above, `reshape2::dcast(X3 ~ X1, data = df, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = "X2")` should do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in base R (suppose your data are in data frame `df`):

```
r <- aggregate(X2~X1+X3, df[df$X3 %in% c(1,2),], mean)
round(t(xtabs(X2~X1+X3, r)), 2)

#   X1
#X3     s1    s2    s3    s4    s5
#  1 45.12  0.00  0.00  0.00 25.45
#  2 49.32  0.00 43.58  0.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
df.mean <- df[, mean(X2), by = .(X1, X3)]
df.mean.wide <- dcast(df.mean, X3 ~ X1, value.var = "V1")
df.mean.wide[is.na(df.mean.wide)] <- 0
df.mean.wide[1:2]

   X3       s1 s2    s3 s4    s5
1:  1 45.12000  0  0.00  0 25.45
2:  2 49.31667  0 43.58  0  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the newer `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages. The following example is aimed at breaking out the two steps (#1 summarizing your data; #2 converting to wide format):

```
library(dyplr)
library(tidyr)

# fake example data set
data_frame(
  X1 = rep(paste0("S", 1:5), times = 6),
  X2 = c(1:30) * 0.1,
  X3 = rep(1:10, each = 3)
) %>% 
  # summarize to calculate mean for each X1 & X3 group
  group_by(X1, X3) %>%
  summarize(X2.avg = mean(X2)) %>% 
  # spread into wide format with 0s for all missing combinations
  spread(X1, X2.avg, fill = 0) %>% 
  # if you really only want to look at the first two X3s
  filter(X3 < 3)
```