# Equal(?) functions not returning same values

Tags: r

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966578/horizontal-to-vertical-format-in-r) when I came across with a question.

Why (in the post's dataframe) this function doesn't return the same value

```
>df[df$X3==c(1,2),]

   X1    X2 X3
1  s1 45.11  1
4  s1 51.41  2
10 s1 43.12  2
17 s5 25.40  1
```

as this function?

```
>df[df$X3 %in% c(1,2),] 

   X1    X2 X3
1  s1 45.11  1
2  s1 45.13  1
3  s1 53.42  2
4  s1 51.41  2
9  s3 43.58  2
10 s1 43.12  2
17 s5 25.40  1
18 s5 25.50  1
```

I used to believe that both are kind of equal. What's the difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was solved, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df$X3 == c(1,2)` is not doing what you think. `c(1,2)` is first recycled to have the same length as `length(df$X3)`, then element-wise `==` is performed. Let's take a small example:

```
1:4 == 2:3  ## which is doing `1:4 == c(2,3,2,3)`
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and we get all `FALSE`. On the other hand, if we do

```
1:4 %in% 2:3
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

we get two `TRUE`.

Comment: Should that comment in the first code block be "which is doing `1:4 == ..." not 1:3?